# Loading the color package changes the default color of the fonts

Tags: color

I have three simple files which load colour-related packages although they don't attempt to use any fancy colours.  These are file `col.tex`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
ABC
\end{document}
```

file `col-black.tex`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\textcolor{black}{ABC}
\end{document}
```

and file `xcol.tex`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
ABC
\end{document}
```

I `latex` and then `dvips` (with dvips(k) 5.994) each of them, and I look at the postscripts.  I was expecting to get "ABC" in black in all cases, as if I had not loaded any colour package at all.  However, when visualizing the files with `evince`, this is not the case for file `col.ps`, I get the "ABC" in a very dark grey, but clearly not black.  If I `ps2pdf` the postscripts the differences are even more clear using a large magnification in `acroread`.

If I diff the three postscript files, apart from three mentions in each of them to the dvi file names, a couple of lines show differences: in `col.ps`:

```
%%Page: 1 1
TeXDict begin 1 0 bop Black Black 166 83 a Fa(ABC)p Black
Black eop end
%%Trailer
```

in `col-black.ps`:

```
%%Page: 1 1
TeXDict begin 1 0 bop Black Black 0 TeXcolorgray 166
83 a Fa(ABC)p Black Black Black eop end
%%Trailer
```

and in `xcol.ps`:

```
%%Page: 1 1
TeXDict begin 1 0 bop 0 TeXcolorgray Black 0 TeXcolorgray
166 83 a Fa(ABC)p 0 TeXcolorgray 0 TeXcolorgray eop end
%%Trailer
```

Am I doing anything wrong?  Is this the expected behaviour of the `color` package?  If it is, is there any way to set the default color in the header?

---

The problem seems to be with the definition of `Black`.  In all files it is defined as

```
 /Black{0 0 0 1 setcmykcolor}
```

If I change the definition in `col.ps` to

```
 /Black{0 setgray}
```

I get the proper black I expected.

Comment: You might want to specify which driver you are using when you load the `color` package: TeX itself doesn't do colour, I believe.  Try `texdoc grfguide` to learn about the `color` package options; `texdoc xcolor` for the `xcolor` package.

Comment: In both cases (`color` and `xcolor`) I don't specify any driver, and this loads the `dvips` one, which is the default in TeXLive.

Comment: This could be a pdf viewer issue. I am no PostScript expert, but the PS code `0 TeXcolorgray` is another form of `0 setgray` which means `black`.

Comment: The file which displays grey-ish fonts is the first one, `col.ps`.  The files that use `TeXcolorgray` seem to deliver proper black.

Comment: This must be a viewer issue; `0 0 0 1 setcmykcolor` means black.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The choice of default colour is not really in the control of the `color` package, it is handled in the `def` file for the back end in use (`dvips` here. I'm not sure why its cmyk black isn't as black as rgb but anyway you can force it to use rgb black as the default by setting the colour in the preamble, compare the effect with or without the commented line.

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{color}
%\definecolor{black}{rgb}{0,0,0}\color{black}
\begin{document}

 \rule{2cm}{1cm}

 \textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{\rule{2cm}{1cm}}

 \textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{\rule{2cm}{1cm}}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

Your documents use different color models (and colors given in different color models): `rgb` and `cmyk`. Default color is a cmyk black. And `black` form `color` or `xcolor` is a rgb black.

With `xcolor`, you may convert color from a model to another. Here is an example to defined a cmyk black form rgb black:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{black cmyk}[cmyk]{black}
```

With `xcolor`, you may choose a global color model:

```
\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
```

Here is a complete example to show the differences with black, green and cyan. In this example, each row of a big square contains three small squares: the color from `xcolor`, the color from `xcolor` converted to cmyk model and the color form `xcolor` converted to rgb model. The first row uses the global model `natural` (no conversion), the second row uses the global model `rgb` and the third row uses the global model `cmyk` (note: `black` and `green` from `xcolor` are in rgb color model while `cyan` is in cmyk color model).

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\colorlet{black cmyk}[cmyk]{black}
\colorlet{black rgb}[rgb]{black}
\colorlet{green cmyk}[cmyk]{green}
\colorlet{green rgb}[rgb]{green}
\colorlet{cyan cmyk}[cmyk]{cyan}
\colorlet{cyan rgb}[rgb]{cyan}

\def\myrule{\rule[-5mm]{1cm}{1cm}}
\def\mytest{
\textcolor{black}{\myrule}%
\textcolor{black cmyk}{\myrule}%
\textcolor{black rgb}{\myrule}
\textcolor{green}{\myrule}%
\textcolor{green cmyk}{\myrule}%
\textcolor{green rgb}{\myrule}
\textcolor{cyan}{\myrule}%
\textcolor{cyan cmyk}{\myrule}%
\textcolor{cyan rgb}{\myrule}
}
\def\mytitle{
  \parbox{2.5cm}{Colors}
  \parbox{1cm}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{\texttt{black} (default)}}%
  \parbox{1cm}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{\texttt{black cmyk}}}%
  \parbox{1cm}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{\texttt{black rgb}}}
  \parbox{1cm}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{\texttt{green (default)}}}%
  \parbox{1cm}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{\texttt{green cmyk}}}%
  \parbox{1cm}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{\texttt{green rgb}}}
  \parbox{1cm}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{\texttt{cyan} (default)}}%
  \parbox{1cm}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{\texttt{cyan cmyk}}}%
  \parbox{1cm}{\centering\rotatebox{90}{\texttt{cyan rgb}}}
}
\begin{document}
\mytitle

\selectcolormodel{natural}
\parbox{2.5cm}{Model \texttt{natural}:} \mytest

\selectcolormodel{rgb}
\parbox{2.5cm}{Model \texttt{rgb}:} \mytest

\selectcolormodel{cmyk}
\parbox{2.5cm}{Model \texttt{cmyk}:} \mytest

\end{document}
```

Comment: However, I think that what I get is slightly different from what you describe in your first paragraph: the default is (a) rgb black if no colour-related package is loaded or if I load `xcolor` without any option, and (b) cmyk black if `color` is loaded.  Is that right?  If that's the case, shouldn't the `color` package documentation clearly warn about it?

Comment: @ripero Neither `LaTeX` nor the package `color` define a color model to use in a document. Only package `xcolor` provides a way to apply a global (or local) color model. You may try `\tracingcolors=4` from `xcolor` to show the used colors.

Comment: @ripero ... You are right about default (black) colors with or without `color` or `xcolor`.