# Font colour change caused by \cite{}

Tags: templates

I have noticed in the LaTeX template from the Proceedings of Science publication (here: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/proceedings-of-science-paper/bnjmzbbwffcp ) that whenever \cite{} is used, the text on the same line after the citation becomes very slightly gray (Before the citation the font is (000000), after it is (231f20). I have noticed this is not just a problem for me but is the case for previous articles published with them e.g. attached a screenshot from https://pos.sissa.it/245/030/pdf . How can I adjust the template such that the font colour does not change? A minimum working example is below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{PoS}

\title{MWE}
\ShortTitle{MWE}
\author{\speaker{MWE}}
\abstract{MWE.}
\FullConference{MWE}

\begin{document}

\section{MWE}
    MWE \cite{MWE} MWE 

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
    \bibitem{MWE}
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Web site you mentioned is clearly said that the particular template is maintaining by some body, hence its better to approach them...(sorry to say)....

Answer (score 1):

Building on the (now deleted) answer of Maeve: the class sets the color to `\Black` at the end of internal and external links (such as citations). This macro is defined in `pdfcolor.tex` as `\pdfsetcolor{\cmykBlack}` and `\cmykBlack` is `{0 0 0 1}`, i.e., in the CMYK color model, with 100% Key and no colors. This however is not 'real black' or 'rich black', see for example [xcolor black isn't black enough](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75451/xcolor-black-isnt-black-enough) or [Loading the color package changes the default color of the fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209975/loading-the-color-package-changes-the-default-color-of-the-fonts/). There are differences for printing and on-screen, and between viewers, but you could try different definitions of black to see which is best. Or cheat and use RGB (the PoS class does not mandate the color model in loading the `color` package). In this case changing the definition can be done easily by redefining `\cmykBlack` (for CMYK) or redefining `\Black` (for RGB).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{PoS}

\title{MWE}
\ShortTitle{MWE}
\author{\speaker{MWE}}
\abstract{MWE.}
\FullConference{MWE}

\begin{document}

%\def\cmykBlack{0.75 0.68 0.67 0.9}
\def\cmykBlack{1 1 1 1}
%\definecolor{pitchblack}{rgb}{0,0,0}
%\def\Black{\color{pitchblack}}
\section{MWEs}
    MWE \cite{MWE} MWE 

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
    \bibitem{MWE}
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

For reference, this is the CMYK 1 1 1 1 version on an rgb 0 0 0 background:

[image]

But note that, if the article is actually printed on paper, the printer will not like that much ink, which may bleed on the page. But that is probably not really your concern as an author.